# Use latest version of package in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, packages

The installed package `libnet-amazon-ec2-perl` uses v0.14.1.

How do I update this package to use the latest stable release v0.22.1?

When I try `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libnet-amazon-ec2-perl` it says I already have the latest release which is not correct - `dpkg -s libnet-amazon-ec2-perl` shows 0.14.1.

Also how do I update all packages dependent on `libnet-amazon-ec2-perl` to use v0.22.1?

Comment: which Debian version/derivative are you using?

Comment: As indicated in the tags, he is using Ubuntu. However we don't know the release, but if the version of the package is v0.14.1 then he is using Precise. Ubuntu need to be upgraded (to Raring at least) to use the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt-get update` before checking for package updates.

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-get` command is telling you that you already have the newest *available* version. That means the newest version that is in the repositories. That there is a newer version released is irrelevant unless that version has been packaged as a `.deb` and has been added to whichever repository you are using.

I assume you are using Ubuntu since you have tagged your questio so, but you did not say *which* Ubuntu. The latest Ubuntu version (raring) has version 0.22 as you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libnet-amazon-ec2-perl&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all).
Please update your question with more information if you are not using raring.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. I followed these instructions, and now it's fine.

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnet-amazon-ec2-perl
```

http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/l/libnet-amazon-ec2-perl/install.html